# How to remove extra index from Url and make it user friendly

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2:

I Want to change this route/URL in myproject 
from
http://myproject.com/style/index/index/parameter/paravalue

to 
http://myproject.com/style/parameter/paravalue

This is a custom Url

I have added the route in XML file i.e routes.xml

```
          <route id="style" frontName="style">
              <module name="modulename"/>
          </route>
```

n i have a layout file style_index_index.xml where the template file is included.

/app/vendor/module/etc/di.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
           <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
               instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
               ="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">


<type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
  <arguments>
      <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="style" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="class" xsi:type="string">vendor\module\Controller\Style</item>
              <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
              <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">22</item>
          </item>
      </argument>
  </arguments>
 </type>
 </config>
```

Created the app/vendor/module/controller/Style.php

```
   namespace vendor\module\Controller;

    class Style implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
    {
        protected $actionFactory;
        protected $_response;
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
        ) {
            $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
            $this->_response     = $response;

        }
        public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
        {

            $identifier  = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
            $identifiers = explode('/', $$identifier);
            if (strpos($identifier, 'style') !== false && count($identifiers) == 3) {
                $request->setModuleName('style')->//module name
                    setControllerName('index')->//controller name
                    setActionName('index')->//action name
                    setParam($identifiers[1], $identifiers[2]); //custom parameters
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            return $this->actionFactory->create(
                'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward', ['request' => $request]
            );
        }

    }
```

Comment: are you need only one Url right?

Comment: Yes  i want to change only this one url

Answer (score 0):

By default, Magento have 3part in its URL.

`http://example.com/{frontendname}/{ControllerName}/{Action}/`

every Magento url must have this a pattern. If not internally, then url has `frontend name` and `ControllerName`,`Action`

http://myproject.com/style/index/index/parameter/paravalue.

**Magento internally using url rewrite or custom Router, it is mapped URL  with frontend Name, Controller name, and Action Name .**

A good example is  Catagory and product URL and Magento using URL rewrite.

The custom Router is CMS pages.

For your case, you have to build a custom Route. See how to build a custom router https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-router-in-magento-2.html

**Have change `match` function code.**

```
 public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) {
    $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
    $identifiers = explode('/',$$identifier);
    if (strpos($identifier, 'style') !== false &&  count($identifiers) == 3) {
        $request->setModuleName('style')->//module name
                setControllerName('index')->//controller name
                setActionName('index')->//action name
                setParam($identifiers[1], $identifiers[2]); //custom parameters
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return $this->actionFactory->create(
                    'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward', ['request' => $request]
    );
}
```

Comment: I created the custom Route and added the required code in di.xml .Also Executed the setup commands of upgrade n di compile n deploy but its not working . If i hit the url it shows url not found but old link is working. Also the match function from CustomStyle Controller is not being fired.